Can you use entropy to find good splits in Guess Who?
In the game Guess Who, there are 24 characters with various traits. The objective is to guess the character of your opponent. I was wondering if it makes sense to use entropy as a measure of information gain to assess the strength of a question (e.g. does your character have facial hair?). The approach I have tried so far is to compute the entropy using correct and incorrect as labels. In this case, the initial sample has entropy
$$S_0 = -\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)- \frac{n-1}{n}\log\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$$
where $n=24$ (if we suppose a one player version where the only objective is to guess the character correctly). If we ask a question that separates the group of characters into a left and right group with $n_l$ and $n_r$ members, respectively, my thinking is that the entropy in the left and right groups are
$$ S_l = -\frac{1}{n_l}\log\left(\frac{1}{n_l}\right) - \frac{n_l-1}{n_l}\log\left(\frac{n_l-1}{n_l}\right) $$
$$ S_r = -\frac{1}{n_r}\log\left(\frac{1}{n_r}\right) - \frac{n_r-1}{n_r}\log\left(\frac{n_r-1}{n_r}\right) $$
where $n=n_r+n_l$. But there are two issues I have. First, I am computing the entropy in each group as if there is a possibility that the correct character is in both. This is not possible. I thought about fixing this issue by using the probability that the correct character falls in each group as a weight, i.e.
$$\frac{n_l}{n}S_l+\frac{n_r}{n}S_r$$
but this does not seem right to me. Am I on the right track? Does this make sense? Any guidance is appreciated.

I don't understand your first equation. If any of $n$ players can be your opponent with equal a priori probability then the inital entropy is simply $\log n$

The entropy for a sample of $n$ elements with $K$ possible classes is $\sum_{k=1}^K-p_l\log(p_k)$, where $p_k$ is the probability of an element belonging to class $k$. The first equation is just this expression with a total of two classes (either correct character or not)

This is essentially the problem of designing a decision tree. And there are many different metrics to evaluate such a design which may yield different optimal ones. Leetcode has an introduction with some hands-on programming exercise, where two metrics (entropy and Gini impurity) are compared.
In your approach, you're somehow on the right track to maximize the entropy gain. But $S_l$ and $S_r$ should be recursively defined, not pre-determined. Unless if we are allowed to group the characters as we want (which is unrealistic: not every grouping has a natural question that does the exact separation), we ended up with designing the Huffman code of $[p_1, \cdots, p_n]$ (where $p_i=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $i$ with no further information, based on the principle of indifference.)
